# QLabel inserts (automatic) a blank line

Tags: c++, ios, qt, qlabel, qlistwidget

I have a QT-UI with some labels. It's structured as follows:
[image]

All the labels are in a listwidget, this is vertically scrollable . Before i put a large text to  the labels, I set its maximumWidth. 
When I set the large text to the labels, the QLabel inserts a blank line on the top.
I'm crazy with it! What can I do to get rid of this empty line?

Here's a photo of the basic UI:
[image]

How you can see, I put a green border to some labels, so you can better see the blank line (inserted by QLabel!). I'm just putting text like "visuelle Kontrolle", but QLabel inserts a line break to the begin of my text. So it looks how you can see.

EDIT:
Additionally I put a little piece of code, so you can see what I'm doing here.
First I set the maximumSize for the labels:

```
auto width = listCtrl->verticalScrollBar()->sizeHint().width();
auto items = {
    ui->m_editKKS,
    ui->m_editOrt,
    ui->m_editKurzbezeichnung,
    ui->m_editLetzterSchaden};

for (QLabel* item : items)
{
    auto margin = 15;
    item->setMaximumWidth(item->width() - (width + margin));
    // item->setStyleSheet("border:1px solid green;");
}

ui->m_editTaetigkeit->setMaximumWidth(ui->m_editTaetigkeit->width() - width);
```

Then I put a text, to the controls. For each control I'm using setText:

```
ui->m_editLetzterSchaden->setText("some text comes here...");
and so on...
```

**EDIT:**

I noticed something (probably) quite important. If I build my UI so that it is not embraced by a vertical layout, then the QLabels will be displayed correctly. But if I build them up so that all elements are spanned by a vertical layout, then there is the rendering problem (as described above). This extremely strange behavior is comprehensible and man can be switched back and forth: with QVBoxLayout-> display error, without QVBoxLayout-> no errors, and so on ...

Here you can see the UI-Code **without** vertical layout around the UI-elements:

```
[?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?]
[ui version="4.0"]
 [class]PrjNameMeldung1_5[/class]
 [widget class="QMainWindow" name="PrjNameMeldung1_5"]
  [property name="geometry"]
   [rect]
    [x]0[/x]
    [y]0[/y]
    [width]375[/width]
    [height]444[/height]
   [/rect]
  [/property]
  [property name="windowTitle"]
   [string]MainWindow[/string]
  [/property]
  [widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget"]
   [widget class="QWidget" name="gridLayoutWidget"]
    [property name="geometry"]
     [rect]
      [x]9[/x]
      [y]25[/y]
      [width]361[/width]
      [height]401[/height]
     [/rect]
    [/property]
    [layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout"]
     [item row="3" column="0"]
      [widget class="PrjListControl" name="listWidget"]
       [property name="sizePolicy"]
        [sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding"]
         [horstretch]0[/horstretch]
         [verstretch]0[/verstretch]
        [/sizepolicy]
       [/property]
      [/widget]
     [/item]
     [item row="1" column="0"]
      [widget class="QLabel" name="m_editTPAggregat"]
       [property name="text"]
        [string]TPAggregat[/string]
       [/property]
      [/widget]
     [/item]
     [item row="2" column="0"]
      [widget class="QLabel" name="m_labelAuswahl"]
       [property name="text"]
        [string]Baugruppe[/string]
       [/property]
       [property name="alignment"]
        [set]Qt::AlignCenter[/set]
       [/property]
      [/widget]
     [/item]
     [item row="0" column="0"]
      [widget class="QLabel" name="m_editTP"]
       [property name="text"]
        [string]TP[/string]
       [/property]
       [property name="alignment"]
        [set]Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignTop[/set]
       [/property]
      [/widget]
     [/item]
    [/layout]
   [/widget]
   [widget class="PrjToolBar" name="m_groupMenuBar" native="true"]
    [property name="geometry"]
     [rect]
      [x]9[/x]
      [y]425[/y]
      [width]357[/width]
      [height]16[/height]
     [/rect]
    [/property]
    [property name="sizePolicy"]
     [sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Fixed"]
      [horstretch]0[/horstretch]
      [verstretch]0[/verstretch]
     [/sizepolicy]
    [/property]
    [property name="minimumSize"]
     [size]
      [width]0[/width]
      [height]10[/height]
     [/size]
    [/property]
   [/widget]
   [widget class="PrjNavigationBar" name="m_groupWindowTitle" native="true"]
    [property name="geometry"]
     [rect]
      [x]9[/x]
      [y]9[/y]
      [width]357[/width]
      [height]16[/height]
     [/rect]
    [/property]
    [property name="sizePolicy"]
     [sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Fixed"]
      [horstretch]0[/horstretch]
      [verstretch]0[/verstretch]
     [/sizepolicy]
    [/property]
    [property name="minimumSize"]
     [size]
      [width]0[/width]
      [height]10[/height]
     [/size]
    [/property]
   [/widget]
  [/widget]
 [/widget]
 [customwidgets]
  [customwidget]
   [class]PrjToolBar[/class]
   [extends]QWidget[/extends]
   [header location="global"]controls/Prjtoolbar.h[/header]
   [container]1[/container]
  [/customwidget]
  [customwidget]
   [class]PrjNavigationBar[/class]
   [extends]QWidget[/extends]
   [header location="global"]controls/Prjnavigationbar.h[/header]
   [container]1[/container]
  [/customwidget]
  [customwidget]
   [class]PrjListControl[/class]
   [extends]QListWidget[/extends]
   [header location="global"]controls/Prjlistcontrol.h[/header]
  [/customwidget]
 [/customwidgets]
 [resources/]
 [connections/]
[/ui]
```

And here you can see the UI-Code **with** vertical layout around the UI-elements:

```
[?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?]
[ui version="4.0"]
 [class]PrjNameMeldung1_5[/class]
 [widget class="QMainWindow" name="PrjNameMeldung1_5"]
  [property name="geometry"]
   [rect]
    [x]0[/x]
    [y]0[/y]
    [width]375[/width]
    [height]444[/height]
   [/rect]
  [/property]
  [property name="windowTitle"]
   [string]MainWindow[/string]
  [/property]
  [widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget"]
   [layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout"]
    [item]
     [widget class="PrjNavigationBar" name="m_groupWindowTitle" native="true"]
      [property name="sizePolicy"]
       [sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Fixed"]
        [horstretch]0[/horstretch]
        [verstretch]0[/verstretch]
       [/sizepolicy]
      [/property]
      [property name="minimumSize"]
       [size]
        [width]0[/width]
        [height]10[/height]
       [/size]
      [/property]
     [/widget]
    [/item]
    [item]
     [layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout"]
      [item row="3" column="0"]
       [widget class="PrjListControl" name="listWidget"]
        [property name="sizePolicy"]
         [sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding"]
          [horstretch]0[/horstretch]
          [verstretch]0[/verstretch]
         [/sizepolicy]
        [/property]
       [/widget]
      [/item]
      [item row="1" column="0"]
       [widget class="QLabel" name="m_editTPAggregat"]
        [property name="text"]
         [string]TPAggregat[/string]
        [/property]
       [/widget]
      [/item]
      [item row="2" column="0"]
       [widget class="QLabel" name="m_labelAuswahl"]
        [property name="text"]
         [string]Baugruppe[/string]
        [/property]
        [property name="alignment"]
         [set]Qt::AlignCenter[/set]
        [/property]
       [/widget]
      [/item]
      [item row="0" column="0"]
       [widget class="QLabel" name="m_editTP"]
        [property name="text"]
         [string]TP[/string]
        [/property]
        [property name="alignment"]
         [set]Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignTop[/set]
        [/property]
       [/widget]
      [/item]
     [/layout]
    [/item]
    [item]
     [widget class="PrjToolBar" name="m_groupMenuBar" native="true"]
      [property name="sizePolicy"]
       [sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Fixed"]
        [horstretch]0[/horstretch]
        [verstretch]0[/verstretch]
       [/sizepolicy]
      [/property]
      [property name="minimumSize"]
       [size]
        [width]0[/width]
        [height]10[/height]
       [/size]
      [/property]
     [/widget]
    [/item]
   [/layout]
  [/widget]
 [/widget]
 [customwidgets]
  [customwidget]
   [class]PrjToolBar[/class]
   [extends]QWidget[/extends]
   [header location="global"]controls/Prjtoolbar.h[/header]
   [container]1[/container]
  [/customwidget]
  [customwidget]
   [class]PrjNavigationBar[/class]
   [extends]QWidget[/extends]
   [header location="global"]controls/Prjnavigationbar.h[/header]
   [container]1[/container]
  [/customwidget]
  [customwidget]
   [class]PrjListControl[/class]
   [extends]QListWidget[/extends]
   [header location="global"]controls/Prjlistcontrol.h[/header]
  [/customwidget]
 [/customwidgets]
 [resources/]
 [connections/]
[/ui]
```

Comment: Hi just to clarify: what are you referring to as a "blank line". Is the word you're looking for "margin" or "padding"? It'd help if you annotate your screenshot with a red circle or rectangle showing the area you're referring to.

Comment: The blank line puts QLabel before my text. So it's not a padding, but it looks like a padding. I dont know what QLabel do in his deep logic, but it's surely not a margin

Comment: Besides updating your question, please also provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem you're facing.

Comment: This results from either the ios style or your application style / geometry. Do you have any style sheets in your application? Do you ever set label->height?

Comment: @Martni, I do not have any styleSheets yet. I will implement these later. I do not set the label->height explicit